# Need help with drywall vs microwave door

Tags: drywall, microwave-oven

[image]Need advice on what I can do to the drywall for me to be able to open the microwave door, without leaving a ugly hole in drywall

[image]

Comment: If you can expand the question with the exact problem it will help.  Does the door hit/rub against the drywall when opening?  Or do you want the open door to not bang against the drywall when fully open?

Comment: This appears to a problem of thoughtless kitchen appliance choice/layout/location, not drywall. Swap the microwave for one that opens on the other side would be the least change option. So, you have hinge on the left, get one that's hinge on the right, problem solved. Or get one 2" narrower, or rearrange the cabinet layout so it's not next to the wall, or...

Comment: Need more context in your pics.  Show us the whole front of the microwave, including the cabinet it's fastened to.

Comment: The second picture seems to show the best solution. Run with it.

Answer (score 4):

Move the microwave... problem solved.